# create lua autocommand to make mason window transparent

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to make the Mason window transparent, in neovim, using lua.

Here was suggested to set winbled locally as autocommand but its not using the newer lua api: https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim/discussions/355.

```
autocmd FileType mason setlocal winblend=10
```

I am trying to do the same with lua:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("FileType", {
  pattern = "mason",
  callback = function() vim.opt_local.winblend = 10 end,
})
```

Nothing is happening after sourcing this. No error and no transparent window.